# cmake_path’s PARENT_PATH acts "strangely" when input path has trailing slash

Tags: cmake, trailing-slash

`cmake_path()` can resolve the parent directory of an inputted directory by using the `PARENT_PATH` command. However, it yielded surprizing results (to me at least) in the case the inputted path ends with `/`: the parent directory is not returned!! Instead, it returns the inputted path without the trailing `/`.

My question: is that a bug or a feature?
In case that it is indeed meant to be this way, what is the reasoning that makes returning the input path without the trailing slash appear natural and/or reasonable?

[Documentation of cmake_path() about `PARENT_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_path.html#decomposition).
[A blog post about the same issue](https://www.georglutz.de/blog/2023/05/29/cmake-parent-directory-and-trailing-slashes/) and [link to the author’s CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/sercxanto/cmake_playground/blob/main/parent_directory/parent_directory.cmake).

I am using cmake 3.27.1 .

```
# cmake_path is available since CMake 3.20
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(DemoParentPath CXX)

set(path_in "/absolute/path/parent/child")
cmake_path(GET path_in PARENT_PATH path_out)
message(STATUS "  in: \"${path_in}\",   out: \"${path_out}\"")

set(path_in "/absolute/path/parent/child/")
cmake_path(GET path_in PARENT_PATH path_out)
message(STATUS "  in: \"${path_in}\",   out: \"${path_out}\"")

set(path_in "relative/path/parent/child")
cmake_path(GET path_in PARENT_PATH path_out)
message(STATUS "  in: \"${path_in}\",   out: \"${path_out}\"")

set(path_in "relative/path/parent/child/")
cmake_path(GET path_in PARENT_PATH path_out)
message(STATUS "  in: \"${path_in}\",   out: \"${path_out}\"")
```

Output:

```bash
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
  in: "/absolute/path/parent/child",   out: "/absolute/path/parent"
  in: "/absolute/path/parent/child/",   out: "/absolute/path/parent/child"
  in: "relative/path/parent/child",   out: "relative/path/parent"
  in: "relative/path/parent/child/",   out: "relative/path/parent/child"
Configuring done (0.0s)
```